# Are the page-size going to be doubled in Server-side Rendering (SSR) + React + Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, server-side-rendering

Server-side Rendering (SSR) + React + Redux assumes that server puts both the fully rendered page *and* the inital state of the Redux store into the sent HTML. For a text-heavy page with most of the text also part of the state, doesn't it mean the same information is going to be sent twice (just in different form)? Doesn't that mean we are unnecessarily doubling the page size?

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, but only if you are not compressing your http responses. In this case if all your initial state data is duplicated as the content of the first page rendered by server, you will basically receive twice as much data on page loading phase compared to what you'd get in client-only rendering scenario.

Strictly speaking, you'll waste even more than that. Server-rendered page contains all the html-markup which have to be transmitted over the wire, and which is not there in case of client-only rendering.

But is it really worth worrying about? How many kilobytes of data do you want to save, compared to all the other stuff to be loaded (i.e. images, style-sheets, etc.)?

Also, as I noted above, you can (and probably should) add gzip compression of your response body. Text compression ratio is very high, so duplication can be greatly reduced.